# how to pass the value of some specific cells from datagridview into the report Rdlc?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, report

Now, I don't have a database. I have uploaded the excel file into the DataGridView and have to generate report from these uploaded data. But the report is not in the Table or Matrix format. The client have some specific way for this report. Now I am getting the problem like how to connect datagridview cell values into report. I have tried to use the methods like in vb6 but not working. Please Help..

thank you!

Here is the Structure:

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you provide is more details on the said report? (e.g. structure, contents). I am very willing to help you

Comment: So, all of these blank spaces in the table will be filled from the datagridview cell data

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
Dim reportData As New DataTable
For i As Integer = 0 To 24 'add 25 columns
  reportData.Columns.Add()
Next i
For i As Integer = 0 To 24 'add 25 rows
  reportData.Rows.Add()
Next i
reportData.Rows(0).Item(0) = "Student's details"
reportData.Rows(1).Item(0) = "Name:"
reportData.Rows(1).Item(1) = "Mr Stu Dent"
reportData.Rows(1).Item(2) = "Class:"
reportData.Rows(1).Item(3) = "Physics 101"
reportData.Rows(2).Item(0) = "Roll:"
reportData.Rows(2).Item(1) = "123"
reportData.Rows(2).Item(2) = "Section:"
reportData.Rows(2).Item(3) = "A"
DataGridView1.DataSource = reportData
```

Comment: I am not understanding what are you trying to do..The above image is the structure of the report to be generated.I have all the data in the DataGridView. The blank spaces in the tables suppose after 'Name' is to be filled from the Data Grid View cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of students in your Excel file you MUST use a [`ReportDataSource`](http://gotreportviewer.com/definedata/index.html) for your report.

For example, you can use your `DataGridView.DataSource`.

Use a [`List`](http://gotreportviewer.com/lists/index.html) to obtain the layout in your image.